Main thread being blocked fetching from Firebase
Every time the posts are fetched from cache or not from cache, the app freezes and main thread seems to be blocked. What is causing it to be blocked in this code? I noticed it happens when a lot of posts are being fetched and displayed.
func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping (Result<[PostWithUser], Error>) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        if !self.cachedPosts.isEmpty {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(self.cachedPosts))
            }
            return
        }

        self.postsRef.order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
                return
            }

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(.success([]))
                }
                return
            }

            var userIds = Set<String>()
            var posts: [Post] = []

            for document in documents {
                let data = document.data()

                guard let userId = data["userId"] as? String,
                      let parentId = data["parentId"] as? String,
                      let groupId = data["groupId"] as? String,
                      let text = data["text"] as? String,
                      let isPinned = data["isPinned"] as? Bool,
                      let imageUrl = data["imageUrl"] as? String,
                      let videoUrl = data["videoUrl"] as? String,
                      let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Timestamp,
                      let views = data["views"] as? Int else {
                    continue
                }

                let post = Post(id: document.documentID, userId: userId, parentId: parentId, groupId: groupId, text: text, imageUrl: imageUrl, videoUrl: videoUrl, timestamp: timestamp.dateValue(), isPinned: isPinned, likedBy: [], views: views)
                posts.append(post)
                userIds.insert(userId)
            }

            self.fetchUsers(withIds: Array(userIds)) { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let users):
                    let usersDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: users.map { ($0.id, $0) })
                    let postsWithUsers = posts.compactMap { post -> PostWithUser? in
                        guard let user = usersDict[post.userId] else { return nil }
                        return PostWithUser(post: post, user: user)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cachedPosts = postsWithUsers
                        completion(.success(postsWithUsers))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private func fetchUsers(withIds ids: [String], completion: @escaping (Result<[User], Error>) -> Void) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    var users: [User] = []
    var fetchError: Error?

    for id in ids {
        group.enter()
        self.usersRef.document(id).getDocument { document, error in
            defer { group.leave() }

            if let error = error {
                fetchError = error
                return
            }

            if let document = document, let data = document.data() {
                let user = User(
                    id: id,
                    username: data["username"] as? String ?? "",
                    bio: data["bio"] as? String ?? "",
                    profilePictureUrl: data["profileImageUrl"] as? String ?? "",
                    privateProfile: data["privateProfile"] as? Bool ?? false,
                    privateFollowerList: data["privateFollowerList"] as? Bool ?? false,
                    privateFollowingList: data["privateFollowingList"] as? Bool ?? false,
                    privateReplies: data["privateReplies"] as? Bool ?? false,
                    privateLikes: data["privateLikes"] as? Bool ?? false,
                    accountDeactivated: data["accountDeactivated"] as? Bool ?? false
                )
                users.append(user)
            }
        }
    }

    group.notify(queue: .global()) {
        if let error = fetchError {
            completion(.failure(error))
        } else {
            completion(.success(users))
        }
    }
}

I tried changing the threading for cached fetching, still did not work.

It won’t solve your issue, but as a side note: Firebase callbacks happen on the main thread. Many of your dispatches are redundant.

@jnpdx ohhh thats good to know. Thank you

it looks like you have self.fetchUsers(...) for every self.postsRef....getDocuments{...}, is this really what you want?

Could be that the issue is with how you're displaying this data as the threading here looks like it should be fine.
